# Concise way of flexibly composing a string?

Tags: c++

What's a concise way of flexibly composing a string? I'd prefer not to use a macro.

For example, I may want to convert an int to string with hex format, padded to a width of 10 characters, concatenated to a string, another number, ...

Basically, I want the flexibility of ostringstream/printf, but on a single line of code.

Comment: Does the `lexical_cast` suggestion still apply to the edited question? At first glance it appears it can only convert a single value to string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used something like this before:

```
#include <sstream>

class make_string
{
public:
    make_string() { }

    template <typename T>
    explicit make_string(T && rhs)
    {
        oss << rhs;
    }

    template <typename T>
    make_string &operator<<(T && rhs)
    {
        oss << rhs;
        return *this;
    }

    operator std::string() const
    {
        return oss.str();
    }

    std::string str() const
    {
        return oss.str();
    }

private:
    std::ostringstream oss;
};
```

Usage is like this:

```
string s = make_string() << "Hello, world" << '!' << 42 << 1.0;
```

Or like this:

```
string s = make_string(4.0);
```

It gives you the flexibility of streaming multiple objects in one expression if you want, or immediate conversion of a single type if that's all you need. It will implicitly convert to a `std::string`, so you can assign it directly to one. All it requires is that your type `T` has a stream-insertion operator to a `std::ostream` object.

Alternatively (as suggested by a commenter above), if you're already using Boost in your project, then `boost::lexical_cast()` is another potential choice. You should take a look at its interface and choose the one you like best.

Comment: I think you forgot a constructor: make_string() {}

Comment: @timdiels: Indeed I did.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this utility function:

```
// util.h
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

inline std::string to_str(basic_ostream<char>& str) {
    return dynamic_cast<std::ostringstream&>(str).str();
}
```

Use it like so:

```
// Example.cpp
#include <stdexcept>
#include "util.h"

using namespace std;

void f(int address) {
  runtime_error(to_str(ostringstream() << "Did not find instruction at: " << hex << address)));
}
```

Comment: Seems a bit brittle to me. The user has to remember to use `to_str()` with `ostringstream()` as the first item in the streaming expression.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
template <typename T>
std::string to_str(T&& t)
{
   std::ostringstream out;
   out << t;
   return out.str();
}
```

Comment: `out.str()` is already of type `std::string`.

Comment: @0x499602D2, Good point. Updated the answer. Thank you.